# How do I specify where Entity Framework is locating my database

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I am using EF6 in VS2012 to create a Code First application.  The database is being created in My Documents\Sql Server Databases.  How do I tell it to create the database in App_Data in the project instead?

Answer (score 0):

Change your Connectionsstring:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MyDatabase-Demo.mdf;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase-Demo;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: That doesn't work.  It still put the database in my Sql ServerDatabases folder.

Comment: Actually, when I have the connection string in my web.config file, EF creates the database in memory but never creates the table.  Then when I try to access it, the provider throws an exception that is can't open the database.  The mdf is never saved anywhere

Comment: I have changed my answer. This is the connectionstring from a demoproject (Asp.Net MVC). -> Run -> Regsiter a user -> File (MyDatabase-Demo.mdf) was created in my App_Data folder -> Right-Click at App_Data-Folder -> Add exsisting item -> select my .mdf... i hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

Entity framework determines which database to use by the connectionstring in app.config with the name same as your DbContext object.

you can change this connectionstring with the same name as your DbContext to something following.

```
  <connectionStrings>
  <add   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"  connectionString="Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|mydbfile.mdf;Database=dbname; Trusted_Connection=Yes;" name="CRMContext"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Here DbContext derived class would be CRMContext. You will find class like below.

```
public class CRMContext:DbContext
{

}
```

If you want your DbContext to use different connectionstring, you can pass the same in its constructor.

```
using(var db = new CRMContext("SomeAnotherConnectionString"))
{

}
```

Here, EF automatically search App.config for the connectionstring with name "SomeAnotherConnectionString"